# Cómo resolver este error al intentar insertar?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

base de datos sql oracle. Cuando creo la tabla prestamos e intento insertar me da error, no se que hacer.

```
CREATE TABLE prestamos (
    PrestamoId       INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    LibroId          INTEGER NOT NULL,
    UsuarioId        INTEGER NOT NULL,
    EjemplarId       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FechaPrestamo    DATE,
    FechaDevolucion  DATE
);

INSERT INTO PRESTAMOS (PrestamoId,LibroId,UsuarioId,EjemplarId,FechaPrestamo,FechaDevolucion) 
VALUES ('989','003256980','Pedro Sanchez','365','10/02/2020', '25/02/2020')
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error obtenido?

Comment: Hola! por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade el error exacto que te da (preferible como texto, evita las imágenes)

Comment: Por ahora, estás mandando en el UsuarioID una cadena 'Pedro Sanchez'. Así mismo, en el PrestamoID y LibroID estás enviando cadenas porque las delimitas con comilla simple: `'989'`. Definiste esos campos como INTEGER, envíale los números que espera

Comment: gracias. ya pude resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día

Tus primeros 4 datos los tienes declarados como números; no como cadena de texto. Para los últimos 2 de fecha debes realizar la conversión [TO_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm); es decir, en vez de `'10/02/2020'` debe ser `TO_DATE('10/02/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY')` *(asumo que el formato que pasas es día/Número mes/Año a 4 digitos)* y así cada una.

Comment: gracias........